# Why is XHR request pending forever on live server?

Tags: api, request, endpoint

So i have a react app which if someone is logged in will check for it's account level and based on that will enable or disable features. It worked until it was all localhost, but now i have a server in the cloud and the request is pending forever. Other requests to the same endpoint works fine. I tried changing the address to localhost, but then it looks for the API server on my PC. It's strange because the same endpoint works with other requests. This single request also works on localhost but not if i use server's IP. Here's an image of the Network page of Chrome development tools: https://i.ibb.co/c2r8Js1/Screenshot-at-2019-12-27-15-11-41.png

```
    getLoggedLevel = () => {
    var URL = process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL;
    var URL2 = 'http://localhost:8000/requests'
    axios({
        url: URL,
        method: 'post',
        data: {
            message: 'getLoggedLevel',
            username: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('loggedUser')).username
        }
    }).then(res => {
        this.setState({loggedLevel: res.data.level})

    })
}
```

Edit: I created a separate endpoint for that single request, and it's 404 however in firefox it's 200 for OPTIONS... Now i'm really confused :(

Comment: To identify where the issue is, I would start with separating the frontend and the API and test them in isolation. Check if the API endpoint works as expected manually using for example netcat, telnet, curl or HTTPie.